# Average each day for 25 years in a new dimension of the array in r

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array, dimensions

I have an array with dim= c(36,28,9502) where the first is latitude, second longitude, and third time (in days)

I would like to get an average every 365 in the third dim (as I eliminated leap days). If that is possible it would be great to get it in a four dim, but is not possible, just the result would be great

I tried with apply, but  could not make it work for a jumping sequence of 365, and a for function but I could not make it make the average (I am not fully experiencing)

`ADTN <-c(36,28,9502)
AA <- apply(ADTN, c(1,2), FUN=mean)`

other way

`for (i in seq(0,365,by=1)) {
  A[i] <- seq(0,9502,by=365)
  ADTN <- ADTN[,,A[i]]
  print(ADTN[i]) }`

My expected results are
c(36,28,26,365) where 26 are the years and 365 days. if not just the result for 365 and I collect it back.
Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: if you're taking averages over chunks of 365 days, your final result should be of dim c(36,28, 26)? please can you explain where the extra dimension of 365 is coming from?

Comment: it would be as I need an average of 26 going by 365 days, an average for every 365 days. Sorry if I am not good explaining. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear how to obtain a 4-dimensional result as you require, but something like this may give you averages over chunks of size 365:

```
ADTN <- rnorm(36 * 28 * 9502)
ADTN <- array(ADTN, dim = c(36, 28, 9502))
apply(ADTN, c(1,2), FUN = function(x) {z <- rep(1:(9502/365+1), each = 365, length.out = 9502); by(x, z, mean)})
```

This gives a resulting array of dimensions (27, 36, 28)

Comment: thank you, I really appreciate your help. And what if what i want to get is c(36,28,365) in which 365 is the average for each year (1,366,731, 731+365, ...n+365)